# How to query and display data as a matrix?

Tags: sql-server, database, pivot, display

My query :

```
SELECT *
FROM   
    (SELECT  
         t.Description,
         ISNULL(COUNT(e.EmployeeCode), 0) 
     FROM    
         Employee AS e  
     INNER JOIN 
         Department AS d ON e.DepartmentCode = d.DepartmentCode
     INNER JOIN 
         TermReason AS t ON e.TermReasonCode = t.TermReasonCode  
     WHERE   
         e.terminationdate IS NOT NULL
         AND e.TerminationDate BETWEEN @PeriodStartDate AND @PeriodEndDate) s
PIVOT   
    (COUNT(EmployeeCode) FOR description IN 
        ([Finance], [Human Resources], [Nursing])) pvt
```

My expected results are:

```
Termination Reason Department1 Department2 Department3 etc etc
---------------------------------------------------------------------
    aaa       value1       value2        value 3           value4
    bbb       value1       value2        value 3           value4
    ccc       value1       value2        value 3           value4
    ddd       value1       value2        value 3           value4
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please be descriptive in your question and provide expected results. It will help get an answer greatly. Though this seems like a lengthy read, it's worth it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You also just deleted your variable definitions

Comment: Since you are using pivot it's paramount that you provide a sample data set to go along with your expected output

Comment: I'm going to assume you want something like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT t.Description, t.TermReason, e.EmployeeCode FROM ...) S PIVOT (COUNT(EmployeeCode) FOR Description IN ([Finance], [Human Resources], [Nursing])) P;`

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic Pivot

```
    DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    --Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
    SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
   + QUOTENAME(Week)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Week FROM #StoreSales) AS Weeks
    --Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
    SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
      N'SELECT Store, ' + @ColumnName + '
        FROM #StoreSales
        PIVOT(SUM(xCount) 
              FOR Week IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
    --Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```